# Why does initialising an object's property with null increase the speed?

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing

For some reason, it appears (in Chrome at least) that if you create an object and initialise each of the properties with a null value and then assign a value to each, it is faster than simply leaving the object blank initially.  Why is this the case ([test](http://jsperf.com/object-initalisation-methodology))?

Comment: Your test cases are a bit screwed up IMO. First, the `test` function is unnecessary (I think?), second, you are assigning values to other properties than the ones defined in the object literal (apart from the first test).

Comment: on mine the "Blank" result is the fastest.

Comment: Here is an updated version: http://jsperf.com/object-initalisation-methodology/2. The difference between the empty one and any other case *could* (!) come from the fact that the properties have to be created at runtime instead of "compile time". All the other cases seem to be equally fast (at least they are within the error margin).

Comment: @FelixKling Yes  - that was my bad.  I wanted to try and make the browser not detect that they would be the same object or something, don't know what I was thinking then.  Anyway, for more accurate results I made a new revision, but with different object names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 (Chrome's Javascript engine) has optimizations that define hidden classes to represent particular objects in your Javascript. It is better able to do this when you declare the object's properties at creation time.

> There are two advantages to using hidden classes: property access does
>   not require a dictionary lookup, and they enable V8 to use the classic
>   class-based optimization, inline caching.

https://developers.google.com/v8/design#prop_access